# Laravel 4.2 Subdomain Sessions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel-4, session-variables, session-cookies

I have dynamic sub-domain routing setup with wild cards. In my app/config/session.php I have:

```
'session' => '.mydomain.com',
'driver' => 'database',
```

When I login at mydomain.com it works, I get

```
Auth::check()==TRUE
```

When I head over to mysubdomain.mydomain.com

```
Auth::check()==FALSE
```

When I go back to mydomain.com after visiting mysubdomain.mydomain.com

```
Auth::check()==FALSE
```

Last note, my .htaccess file redirects all www.mydomain.com requests to mydomain.com.

When I inspect resources/cookies in chrome on mydomain.com I see only one cookie with

```
domain .mydomain.com
```

When I inspect resources/cookies at mysubdomain.mydomain.com I see two cookies:

```
.mydomain.com 
mysubdomain.mydomain.com
```

Anyone have a tip for me? Can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Has anyone tries this in Laravel 5.1 yet? I'm porting over, maybe it has been fixed?

Comment: Hey! Did you make sure that your config/session.php on the subdomain reflects the same configuration? I have two websites that have two different subdomain and it's sharing sessions. It's on 2 different servers to boot! I'm just curious what's going on with yours. :) Did you ever figure it out??

Comment: Its the same application, so the config is shared. Your site is down :/